# Positioning text underneath and position:fixed image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a Boostrap website with a navbar across the top and two columns divs in a row. The first column contains an image and should always stay fixed in position. The second column contains (potentially) a page or two of text and should scroll independently.

I've used `position:fixed` to hold the image in position, but my issue is that I would then like to add a link underneath it that links to the terms and conditions for the page.

[image]

[BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/Jgqq5AA2ZF)

Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: an image speaks'em 1000. A snip of code 10000

Comment: You can set the Y coordination of the text to the height of the image, you can add more to give more space.

Comment: IF the image height is not going to change, than yes. Use position Fixed for your T&C link. Otherwise there's no need to set position fixed to your image at all. Or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a couple ways of doing this. I won't go into code since you don't have anything to work off of so I hope you can understand my explanations.

1. You can try simply putting the link `position: fixed` as well and set the `top` property of the link element so that it'll be positioned below your image (you can play around with this).
2. Use a `div` that is set to `position: fixed` that will contain both the image and the link. Then you can just simple put the image inside the div without any positioning and the link should go underneath the image without any positioning either.
3. You can set the text on the right side to be `overflow: scroll` and set the width/height of the right text in the div so that it can scroll. This will essentially keep the document still but allows the user to scroll up and down the text content inside the right side div.

Number 1 is the quickest solution, number 2 IMO is the best solution. If you need some help with the code, post a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a go and get back to you.

Comment: I've added a bootply link above, but if I add the position:fixed to the first column div in Line 2, the columns overlay each other.

Comment: @MarkG Forked: http://www.bootply.com/Th22p7xX8n. I did #2, used a container div that is fixed inside of the column.

Comment: @MarkG, if this answer helped make sure to tick it as the answer! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/oktZkPPE7Q)

```
 <div style="position:fixed">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x300" class="img-responsive">
     <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a> - <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I looked at Affix, but it doesn't quite do what I need, I think. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Or you can use position fixed also

Comment: If your issue solved with help of my answer means pls tick my answer